# Oauth2-proxy static directory configuration not working using upstream

Tags: docker, oauth2-proxy

I am trying to create my custom login page for oauth2-proxy and following the documentation here: https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/overview#upstreams-configuration

I created docker environment variable and passed path location as upstream variable:

```
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_UPSTREAM
          value: http://application-1:8080,file:///home/oauth2/login/#/oauth2/login/
```

I place my static files under path /home/oauth2/login.

But I can't access the static directory here:

```
http:<oauth2-url>:<port>:/oauth2/login/
```

It always redirect to sign_in.html page.

Can any one please help if I am missing anything.